# Splitting the name when a word matches with one in array?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, split

As a part of my learning. After i successfully split with help, in my next step, wanted to know if i can split the names of files when the month name is found in the name of the file that matches with the name of the month given in this list below ---
Months=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'].

When my file name is like this 
1.Non IVR Entries Transactions December_16_2016_07_49_22 PM.txt
2.Denied_Calls_SMS_Sent_December_14_2016_05_33_41 PM.txt

Please note that the names of files is not same..i.e why i need to split it like 
Non IVR Entries Transactions as one part and December_16_2016_07_49_22 PM as another.

```
import os
import os.path
import csv
path = 'C:\\Users\\akhilpriyatam.k\\Desktop\\tes'
text_files = [os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(path)]
for v in text_files:
    print (v[0:9])
    print (v[10:])
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\akhilpriyatam.k\\Desktop\\tes')
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
thedatawriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
for v in text_files:
    s = (v[0:9])
    t = (v[10:])
    thedatawriter.writerow([s,t])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
import calendar
fullname = 'Non IVR Entries Transactions December_16_2016_07_49_22 PM.txt'
months = list(calendar.month_name[1:])
regex = re.compile('|'.join(months))
iter = re.finditer(regex, fullname)
if iter:
    idx = [it for it in iter][0].start()
    filename, timestamp = fullname[:idx],fullname[idx:-4]
    print filename, timestamp
else:
    print "Month not found"
```

Assuming that you want the filename and timestamp as splits and the month occurs only once in the string, I hope the following code solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, I have different file names, if i run them in a loop, i still am getting Non ivr entires only. Something is wrong and im not able to figure out what!

Comment: Could you give a link to some sample lines in the csv you are using?

Comment: I have found the answer. Thanks